# Drop duplicates after merging 2 dataframes with inner join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to merge two dataframes using pandas merge function with inner join. H0002 and H0003 is equal to ordrenr and radnr in the second dataframe. df_1 has 268643 and df_2 has 203124 rows. When I merge them, the resulting dataframe has 5303556 rows.. I have tried to use drop_duplicates and dup, but the duplicates aren't removed. How should I merge the two dataframes and retain a new dataframe with no duplicates?
[image: my approach]

Comment: drop_duplicates() after merged doesnt make any change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop duplicates use

```py
merged_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```